conda install python UnsatisfiableError
I'm trying to update my python version with this command:
conda install python=3.12.0

But I get an insanely long UnsatisfiableError message. I've read another question regarding this error, but that one has only one incompatible dependency that you can manage manually, whereas in my case, it prints this:
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with a past
explicit spec that is not an explicit spec in this operation (openssl):

  - python=3.12.0 -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0'] -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0|>=7.5.0']
  - python=3.12.0 -> expat[version='>=2.5.0,<3.0a0'] -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=11.2.0|>=7.5.0']
  - python=3.12.0 -> ld_impl_linux-64[version='>=2.35.1']
  - python=3.12.0 -> libffi[version='>=3.4,<4.0a0']
  - python=3.12.0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build=main]
  - python=3.12.0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> _openmp_mutex
  - python=3.12.0 -> libuuid[version='>=1.41.5,<2.0a0']
  - python=3.12.0 -> ncurses[version='>=6.4,<7.0a0']
  - python=3.12.0 -> openssl[version='>=3.0.11,<4.0a0'] -> ca-certificates
  - python=3.12.0 -> pip -> setuptools
  - python=3.12.0 -> pip -> wheel
  - python=3.12.0 -> readline[version='>=8.0,<9.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.3,<7.0a0']
  - python=3.12.0 -> sqlite[version='>=3.41.2,<4.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<2.0a0']
  - python=3.12.0 -> tk[version='>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0']
  - python=3.12.0 -> tzdata
  - python=3.12.0 -> xz[version='>=5.4.2,<6.0a0']
  - python=3.12.0 -> zlib[version='>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package xz conflicts for:
conda[version='>=22.9.0'] -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.4.2,<6.0a0|>=5.4.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.4.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0']
brotlipy -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.2.3,<6.0a0|>=5.4.6,<6.0a0|>=5.4.2,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0|>=5.4.5,<6.0a0']
pluggy -> python[version='>=3.12,<3.13.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.4.2,<6.0a0|>=5.4.5,<6.0a0|>=5.4.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.2.3,<6.0a0']
pycparser -> python[version='>=3.6'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.4.2,<6.0a0|>=5.4.5,<6.0a0|>=5.4.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.2.3,<6.0a0']
certifi -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.4.2,<6.0a0|>=5.4.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.4.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.2.3,<6.0a0']
urllib3 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.4.2,<6.0a0|>=5.4.5,<6.0a0|>=5.4.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.2.3,<6.0a0']
idna -> python[version='>=3.12,<3.13.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.4.2,<6.0a0|>=5.4.5,<6.0a0|>=5.4.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.2.3,<6.0a0']
zstd -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.4.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0']
pycosat -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.4.2,<6.0a0|>=5.4.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.4.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.2.3,<6.0a0']
wheel -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.4.2,<6.0a0|>=5.4.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.4.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.3,<6.0a0']
six -> python -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.4.2,<6.0a0|>=5.4.5,<6.0a0|>=5.4.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.2.3,<6.0a0']
pyopenssl -> python[version='>=3.12,<3.13.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.4.2,<6.0a0|>=5.4.5,<6.0a0|>=5.4.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.2.3,<6.0a0']
conda-content-trust -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.4.2,<6.0a0|>=5.4.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.4.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.3,<6.0a0']
toolz -> python[version='>=3.12,<3.13.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.4.2,<6.0a0|>=5.4.5,<6.0a0|>=5.4.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.2.3,<6.0a0']
pip -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.4.2,<6.0a0|>=5.4.5,<6.0a0|>=5.4.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.2.3,<6.0a0']
conda-package-streaming -> python[version='>=3.12,<3.13.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.4.2,<6.0a0|>=5.4.5,<6.0a0|>=5.4.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0']
conda-package-handling -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.4.2,<6.0a0|>=5.4.5,<6.0a0|>=5.4.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.2.3,<6.0a0']
pysocks -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.4.6,<6.0a0|>=5.4.5,<6.0a0|>=5.4.2,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0|>=5.2.3,<6.0a0']
cffi -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.4.2,<6.0a0|>=5.4.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.4.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0|>=5.2.3,<6.0a0']
ruamel_yaml -> python[version='>=3.12,<3.13.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.4.2,<6.0a0|>=5.4.5,<6.0a0|>=5.4.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.2.3,<6.0a0']
brotli-python -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.4.2,<6.0a0|>=5.4.5,<6.0a0|>=5.4.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.2.3,<6.0a0']
setuptools -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.4.2,<6.0a0|>=5.4.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.4.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.2.3,<6.0a0']
cryptography -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.4.2,<6.0a0|>=5.4.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.4.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.2.3,<6.0a0']
tqdm -> python[version='>=3.12,<3.13.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.4.2,<6.0a0|>=5.4.5,<6.0a0|>=5.4.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.2.3,<6.0a0']
zstandard -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.4.2,<6.0a0|>=5.4.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.4.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.2.3,<6.0a0']
charset-normalizer -> python[version='>=3.5'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.4.2,<6.0a0|>=5.4.5,<6.0a0|>=5.4.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.2.3,<6.0a0']
xz
requests -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.10,<6.0a0|>=5.4.2,<6.0a0|>=5.4.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.8,<6.0a0|>=5.2.6,<6.0a0|>=5.2.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0|>=5.4.5,<6.0a0|>=5.2.3,<6.0a0']

Package cryptography conflicts for:
cryptography
pyopenssl -> cryptography[version='>=1.9|>=2.1.4|>=2.2.1|>=2.8|>=3.3|>=35.0|>=38.0.0,<40|>=38.0.0,<42,!=40.0.0,!=40.0.1|>=41.0.5,<43']
conda[version='>=22.9.0'] -> pyopenssl[version='>=16.2.0'] -> cryptography[version='>=1.9|>=2.1.4|>=2.2.1|>=2.8|>=3.3|>=35.0|>=38.0.0,<40|>=38.0.0,<42,!=40.0.0,!=40.0.1|>=41.0.5,<43']
conda-content-trust -> cryptography[version='<41.0.0a0|>=41']
requests -> urllib3[version='>=1.21.1,<3'] -> cryptography[version='>=1.3.4']
urllib3 -> cryptography[version='>=1.3.4']
urllib3 -> pyopenssl[version='>=0.14'] -> cryptography[version='>=1.9|>=2.1.4|>=2.2.1|>=2.8|>=3.3|>=35.0|>=38.0.0,<40|>=38.0.0,<42,!=40.0.0,!=40.0.1|>=41.0.5,<43']

Package tzdata conflicts for:
tqdm -> python[version='>=3.12,<3.13.0a0'] -> tzdata
conda[version='>=22.9.0'] -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> tzdata
urllib3 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> tzdata
cffi -> python[version='>=3.12,<3.13.0a0'] -> tzdata
cryptography -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tzdata
tzdata
pysocks -> python[version='>=3.12,<3.13.0a0'] -> tzdata
requests -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> tzdata
idna -> python[version='>=3.12,<3.13.0a0'] -> tzdata
zstandard -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> tzdata
ruamel_yaml -> python[version='>=3.12,<3.13.0a0'] -> tzdata
pyopenssl -> python[version='>=3.12,<3.13.0a0'] -> tzdata
pluggy -> python[version='>=3.12,<3.13.0a0'] -> tzdata
setuptools -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tzdata
toolz -> python[version='>=3.12,<3.13.0a0'] -> tzdata
wheel -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> tzdata
conda-content-trust -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> tzdata
pycparser -> python[version='>=3.6'] -> tzdata
six -> python -> tzdata
brotli-python -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> tzdata
brotlipy -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tzdata
pip -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> tzdata
charset-normalizer -> python[version='>=3.5'] -> tzdata
certifi -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tzdata
conda-package-handling -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> tzdata
conda-package-streaming -> python[version='>=3.12,<3.13.0a0'] -> tzdata
pycosat -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> tzdata

Package bzip2 conflicts for:
urllib3 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']
pip -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']
requests -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']
pycosat -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']
idna -> python[version='>=3.12,<3.13.0a0'] -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']
setuptools -> python[version='>=3.12,<3.13.0a0'] -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']
cffi -> python[version='>=3.12,<3.13.0a0'] -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']
pysocks -> python[version='>=3.12,<3.13.0a0'] -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']
conda-package-streaming -> python[version='>=3.12,<3.13.0a0'] -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']
conda[version='>=22.9.0'] -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']
zstandard -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']
cryptography -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']
certifi -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']
conda-content-trust -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']
conda-package-handling -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.6,<2.0a0|>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']
brotlipy -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']
pyopenssl -> python[version='>=3.12,<3.13.0a0'] -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']
pluggy -> python[version='>=3.12,<3.13.0a0'] -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']
pycparser -> python[version='>=3.6'] -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']
toolz -> python[version='>=3.12,<3.13.0a0'] -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']
wheel -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']
six -> python -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']
brotli-python -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']
ruamel_yaml -> python[version='>=3.12,<3.13.0a0'] -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']
charset-normalizer -> python[version='>=3.5'] -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']
bzip2
tqdm -> python[version='>=3.12,<3.13.0a0'] -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0']

Package conda-package-streaming conflicts for:
conda-package-handling -> conda-package-streaming[version='>=0.7.0|>=0.9.0']
conda-package-streaming
conda[version='>=22.9.0'] -> conda-package-handling[version='>=2.2.0'] -> conda-package-streaming[version='>=0.7.0|>=0.9.0']

Package _openmp_mutex conflicts for:
libgcc-ng -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
conda-package-handling -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
libffi -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
ncurses -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
cffi -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
cryptography -> libgcc-ng -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
zstd -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
openssl -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
zlib -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
lz4-c -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
readline -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
bzip2 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
_openmp_mutex
ruamel_yaml -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
brotli-python -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
yaml -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
sqlite -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
tk -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
brotlipy -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
zstandard -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
xz -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
pycosat -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
libuuid -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']

[[[[[SKIPPING LIKE 80% OF THE MESSAGE BECAUSE OF TOO MANY CHARACTERS]]]]]]

Package brotli-python conflicts for:
brotli-python
requests -> urllib3[version='>=1.21.1,<3'] -> brotli-python[version='>=1.0.9']
urllib3 -> brotli-python[version='>=1.0.9']

Package tk conflicts for:
pysocks -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> tk[version='8.6.*|>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.14,<8.7.0a0']
pyopenssl -> python[version='>=3.12,<3.13.0a0'] -> tk[version='8.6.*|>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.14,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
pluggy -> python[version='>=3.12,<3.13.0a0'] -> tk[version='8.6.*|>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.14,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
pycparser -> python[version='>=3.6'] -> tk[version='8.6.*|>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.14,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
conda-package-streaming -> python[version='>=3.12,<3.13.0a0'] -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.14,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
setuptools -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tk[version='8.6.*|>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.14,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
six -> python -> tk[version='8.6.*|>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.14,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
cffi -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> tk[version='8.6.*|>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.14,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
conda-content-trust -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> tk[version='8.6.*|>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.14,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
conda[version='>=22.9.0'] -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.14,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
brotli-python -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> tk[version='8.6.*|>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.14,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
toolz -> python[version='>=3.12,<3.13.0a0'] -> tk[version='8.6.*|>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.14,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
wheel -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> tk[version='8.6.*|>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.14,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
certifi -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tk[version='8.6.*|>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.14,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
tqdm -> python[version='>=3.12,<3.13.0a0'] -> tk[version='8.6.*|>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.14,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
pip -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> tk[version='8.6.*|>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.14,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
charset-normalizer -> python[version='>=3.5'] -> tk[version='8.6.*|>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.14,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
conda-package-handling -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> tk[version='8.6.*|>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.14,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
tk
pycosat -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> tk[version='8.6.*|>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.14,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
brotlipy -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> tk[version='8.6.*|>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.14,<8.7.0a0']
ruamel_yaml -> python[version='>=3.12,<3.13.0a0'] -> tk[version='8.6.*|>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.14,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
cryptography -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tk[version='8.6.*|>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.14,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
requests -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> tk[version='8.6.*|>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.14,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
idna -> python[version='>=3.12,<3.13.0a0'] -> tk[version='8.6.*|>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.14,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
zstandard -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> tk[version='8.6.*|>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.14,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
urllib3 -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> tk[version='8.6.*|>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.11,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.12,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.14,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']

Package ipaddress conflicts for:
conda-content-trust -> cryptography[version='<41.0.0a0'] -> ipaddress
requests -> urllib3[version='>=1.21.1,<3'] -> ipaddress
pyopenssl -> cryptography[version='>=2.8'] -> ipaddress
urllib3 -> ipaddress
cryptography -> ipaddress

Package brotlipy conflicts for:
brotlipy
urllib3 -> brotlipy[version='>=0.6.0']
requests -> urllib3[version='>=1.21.1,<3'] -> brotlipy[version='>=0.6.0']

Package conda-package-handling conflicts for:
conda-package-handling
conda[version='>=22.9.0'] -> conda-package-handling[version='>=1.3.0|>=2.2.0']

Package pyopenssl conflicts for:
requests -> urllib3[version='>=1.21.1,<3'] -> pyopenssl[version='>=0.14']
conda[version='>=22.9.0'] -> pyopenssl[version='>=16.2.0']
urllib3 -> pyopenssl[version='>=0.14']
pyopenssl

Package zstandard conflicts for:
conda-package-handling -> zstandard[version='>=0.15']
conda[version='>=22.9.0'] -> zstandard[version='>=0.19.0']
zstandard
conda-package-streaming -> zstandard[version='>=0.15']
conda[version='>=22.9.0'] -> conda-package-handling[version='>=2.2.0'] -> zstandard[version='>=0.15']

Package toolz conflicts for:
conda[version='>=22.9.0'] -> toolz[version='>=0.8.1']
toolz

Package libgomp conflicts for:
libgcc-ng -> _openmp_mutex -> libgomp[version='>=7.5.0']
_openmp_mutex -> libgomp[version='>=7.5.0']
libgomp

Package tqdm conflicts for:
conda[version='>=22.9.0'] -> conda-package-handling[version='>=1.3.0'] -> tqdm
tqdm
conda-package-handling -> tqdm
conda[version='>=22.9.0'] -> tqdm[version='>=4']

Package pluggy conflicts for:
conda[version='>=22.9.0'] -> pluggy[version='>=1.0.0']
pluggy

Package yaml conflicts for:
yaml
ruamel_yaml -> yaml[version='>=0.1.7,<0.2.0a0|>=0.2.5,<0.3.0a0']
conda[version='>=22.9.0'] -> ruamel_yaml[version='>=0.11.14,<0.17'] -> yaml[version='>=0.1.7,<0.2.0a0|>=0.2.5,<0.3.0a0']

Package urllib3 conflicts for:
urllib3
requests -> urllib3[version='>=1.21.1,<1.23|>=1.21.1,<1.24|>=1.21.1,<1.25|>=1.21.1,<1.26,!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1|>=1.21.1,<1.27|>=1.21.1,<2|>=1.21.1,<3']
conda[version='>=22.9.0'] -> requests[version='>=2.28.0,<3'] -> urllib3[version='>=1.21.1,<1.24|>=1.21.1,<1.25|>=1.21.1,<1.26,!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1|>=1.21.1,<1.27|>=1.21.1,<2|>=1.21.1,<3']

Package pysocks conflicts for:
pysocks
requests -> urllib3[version='>=1.21.1,<3'] -> pysocks[version='>=1.5.6,<2.0,!=1.5.7']
urllib3 -> pysocks[version='>=1.5.6,<2.0,!=1.5.7']

Package ruamel_yaml conflicts for:
conda[version='>=22.9.0'] -> ruamel_yaml[version='>=0.11.14,<0.17']
ruamel_yaml

Package pycosat conflicts for:
conda[version='>=22.9.0'] -> pycosat[version='>=0.6.3']
pycosat

Package wheel conflicts for:
wheel
pip -> wheel

Package charset-normalizer conflicts for:
charset-normalizer
conda[version='>=22.9.0'] -> requests[version='>=2.28.0,<3'] -> charset-normalizer[version='>=2,<3|>=2,<4|>=2.0.0,<3|>=2.0.0,<2.1.0']
conda[version='>=22.9.0'] -> charset-normalizer
requests -> charset-normalizer[version='>=2,<3|>=2,<4|>=2.0.0,<3|>=2.0.0,<2.1.0']

Package enum34 conflicts for:
urllib3 -> cryptography[version='>=1.3.4'] -> enum34
pyopenssl -> cryptography[version='>=2.8'] -> enum34
conda-content-trust -> cryptography[version='<41.0.0a0'] -> enum34
cryptography -> enum34

Package requests conflicts for:
requests
conda[version='>=22.9.0'] -> requests[version='>=2.20.1,<3|>=2.27.0,<3|>=2.28.0,<3']The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.38=0
  - feature:|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.38=0
  - brotli-python -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - brotlipy -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - bzip2 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - cffi -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - conda-package-handling -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - cryptography -> libgcc-ng -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libffi -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libgcc-ng -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libstdcxx-ng -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libuuid -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - lz4-c -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - ncurses -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - openssl -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - pycosat -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - python=3.12.0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - readline -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - ruamel_yaml -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - sqlite -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - tk -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - xz -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - yaml -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - zlib -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - zstandard -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - zstd -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']

Your installed version is: 2.38


It's as if every single package has a conflict. Obviously, I can't manually go and resolve all of them, and also this just seems really really weird, this shouldn't happen.

what version of conda and python are you currenly using?

@James conda=23.9.0, python=3.11.0.final.0. I updated to 3.11 after writing this question with no issues, but I still can't update to 3.12.0

is this the base environment you are trying to update?

@James yes, base

Generally speaking, you don't update the version of Python in the base environment.  Conda in that env runs on that version of Python, asking it to uninstall Python, then install a new version of Python WILL break stuff.  If you need a new version of Python, you should create a new environment. conda create -n new-env python=3.12 ...
